# vue.js - can you define and populate a template in the same html where mounted element is located?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Sort of having crash course on vue. I want to make a dialog popup to edit one of the several entities, let's say from a list. I want to keep it all together in this html file. Currently I ended up with something like this:

- an array of source objects;
- dialogEntity as a source object for dialog form.

When entity needs to be edited it is assigned to dialogEntity and template dialog element is made visible.

```
<div id="vue-app">
    <button @click="showEditDialog(entities[0])" > Click me </button>

    <template>
        <div id="editEntityDialog">
            <h2>{{ dialogEntity.someField }}</h2>
        </div>
    </template>
</div>

<script>
    createApp({
        data() {
            return {
                entities: [ ... ], // some objects
                dialogEntity: {},
            }
        },

        methods: {
            showEditDialog(entity) {
                this.dialogEntity = entity;
                $("#editEntityDialog").dialog();
            }
        }

    }).mount('#vue-app')
</script>
```

But I have a feeling it could be done in a different way.
I would like to move the template out of [div id="vue-app"] element and be able to populate it in some other way, something like selecting arbitrary template text in the showEditDialog function and bind it to parameter object.

Is it possible to do this without using component defined in other files?

Answer (score 0):

It is unusual to define all your templates and script data in the file where you create & mount your Vue app, if you are learning I would suggest if you want to be able to read, use & contribute to other peoples code you need to extract your templates & script logic to individual component files. Even in small projects, this is still a good idea as it is the excepted convention on how to handle the structure of your data.

Also another suggestion would be naming your objects / entities with meaningful names so that they are more human readable in that, if someone else is to look at your project it is much easier for them to understand and work out what it is that your code does. Rather than use entities refer to what the entities actually are.

To answer your actual question, another way of doing this & to stick with the way most people would handle this is to to define & use reactive variable that can be used in v-show or v-if to conditionally render your dialog.

Something like this:

```
<button @click.prevent="dialogShow = !dialogShow"
<div v-show="dialogShow">
let dialogShow = ref(false)
```

Sorry for the compositions api formatting (I much prefer the compositions API)